# Modificar Instancia desde otra Instancia en la Misma Base de Datos. Firebase

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

en esta oportunidad tengo un pequeño requerimiento que no he podido llevar a cabo.

Tengo una chica base de datos estructurado de esta forma;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en `AP` sera cargado un dato todos los dias, el cual siempre ocupara la ultima posiciones obviamente, necesito que este ultimo dato tambien se cargue pase a la instancia  `SA`.

Intente algo como esto;

```
AP.on('value',(snap)=>{
    let ap_val = snap.val();
    let ap_val_l = ap_val.length -1;
    SA.push(ap_val[ap_val_l]);
});
```

donde a travez del evento `on` pues cada vez que modifique `AP` en este caso en la carga diaria del ultimo item, con `push` lo agregue a  `SA` el cual es mi propósito. y realmente funciona, el problema es que cada vez que la pagina carga hace esta tarea, y no es el objetivo.

Lo que necesito es que cada vez que `AP` se modifique, se cargue el dato nuevo  a `SA` solo una vez y así al próximo día nuevamente cuando `AP` se le cargue el dato diario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que podrias hacer es revisar si ese dato con ese `key` que seria 0,1,2,3,4,5 como lo tienes en el grafico ya existe, ya que como estas usando el evento `on` se va a ejecutar cada vez que reinicies la pagina.

De esta manera, antes de hacer push, verificas y si no existe lo agregas :D.

Creo que el codigo seria asi.

```
//LimitToLast(1): Obtener el ultimo valor
AP.limitToLast(1).on('value', (snap) => {
    let ap_key = snap.key; //Obtener la key
    let ap_value = spap.val(); //Obtener el valor
    //Verificar si la llave existe en SA
    SA.child(ap_key.toString()).once('value', function (snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.exists()) {
            SA.push({ap_key : ap_value}); //Agregar la data en SA
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: he probado tu codigo, no hace nada, es decir cuando agrego un elemento en AP no me agrega nada en SA. :(

Comment: Hola, e falto la ! En el snapshot.exist() intenta con el codigo que he modificado :D

Comment: lo he modificado y funciona agregando el ultimo valor de `AP` en `SA`, pero con una key diferente 'aleatoria' creada por firebase me imagino, por lo tanto cada vez que se actualiza la web crea el mismo ultimo  valor de `AP`, con key diferentes. como podríamos setear la clave original de `AP`. Gracias!

Comment: lo he actualizado :D

Comment: estupendo, me ha funcionado tal cual, crees que es mejor hacerlo por aca o con functions en mi otra pregunta? podrias coolaborarme con la function para hacerlo de ambas maneras, gracias!

Comment: Nunca he trabajado con functions pero si veo como seria, te comparto el codigo :D

Comment: vale perfecto, muchas gracias por tu tiempo y ayuda.